# Hide/Show Div Tag based on RadioButtonList selected value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a situation where i have to show/Hide DIV TAG based on Checkbox selection. Below is the code example

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="ckbRestaurent" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" >   
     <asp:ListItem selected="true" Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>  
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<div id="xyz"> something.. </div>
```

I tried several ways but it didn't work as i am new to jQuery, I would appreciate if someone would give me a working example for the above code .

It should by default hide div on page load and show DIV when user select the YES option in the RadioButtonList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i wanted solution using the exact HTML show in my question. SO i found a solution which is as

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#RadioDiv input').click(function () {
     $("#info").text('Selected Value: ' + $("#RadioDiv input:radio:checked").val());
         if ($("#RadioDiv input:radio:checked").val() == 0) {
              document.getElementById('Restaurent').style.display = "none";
              }
              else {
              document.getElementById('Restaurent').style.display = "";
                    }
       });
     }); 
</script>
```

HTML CODE BELOW

```
<div id="RadioDiv">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="ckbRestaurent" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" >   
  <asp:ListItem selected="true" Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>  
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
<table class="style1">
      <tr>
         <td ></td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td ></td><td></td>
       </tr>
</table>
    </br>
<div id="Restaurent" style="display:none" >
<!-- Details Group Restaurent Table -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableDetailsGroupOne">
  <tr>
      <td class="tableDetailsGroupOneLabel">Restaurant One:</td>
      <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtRestaurentOne" runat="server" CssClass="txtNameOfHotel">Restaurent One</asp:TextBox>
      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td class="tableDetailsGroupOneLabel">Restaurent Two:</td>
      <td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRestaurentTwo" runat="server" CssClass="txtNameOfHotel" ></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- Details Group Restaurent Table END-->
```

I also appreciate other user who also replied to my question, since i wanted solution using for ASP.NET server control.

Answer (score 0):

you need to hook a client-side javascript call to your RadioButtonList. in the javascript function you can do something like $("#xyz").hide() or $("#xyz").show()

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#xyz").hide();
        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (){
            if ($(this).attr('checked')){
                $("#xyz").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#xyz").hide();
            }
        });

    });
```

and ple add your html code so that we can modify above script

Comment: Script you have given me only hide the DIV "XYZ" on page_load, I am new to jQuery and i am not able to find where in your code you are checking if the value of check box is 0 or 1, It should would accordingly if value is 1 then it should show DIV otherwise hide DIV. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

i am adding html version as you mentioned. ple try to understand and let me know.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#xyz").hide();
        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (){            
            if ($(this).val()=='0' && $(this).attr('checked')){
                $("#xyz").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#xyz").hide();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" value="0">yes
<input type="checkbox" value="1">no
<div id="xyz"> something.. </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and sorry to mention i am not a .det person. i can help you with jquery and html.

Comment: THis wont help as i have to strictly stick to                                                 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="ckbRestaurent" runat="server" 
                                                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnClientClick =" return chkboxMeth()">
                                                <asp:ListItem selected="true" Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:RadioButtonList>

Comment: No problem i still appreciate your help. Thanks